# Find the sum of ages in JSON array

Tags: javascript

```
  var people = [
  {
    name: 'shihan', //persons name, favorite color, and age
    color: 'blue',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'john',
    color: 'blue',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'pete',
    color: 'blue',
    age: 26
  }
] //json api
var newPerson = people.filter(function(x){ return x.color === 'blue'})
newPerson.map(x => x.name)
newPerson.reduce((a,b) => a.age + b.age)
NaN //output
```

I need to take the age of each person and find the sum, please help! I created an API and I'm using the reduce method to find the age in the people array.

Comment: `newPerson.reduce((a,b) => a + b.age,0)`

Comment: The problem is that in the second round the value of `a` is not an object any more.

Comment: Calling the array a *JSON array* is a misnomer. It's just an array of objects.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, you need to provide a starting value for `Array.protoype.reduce()`, which would be `0` in your case.

```
newPerson.reduce((total, a) => total + a.age, 0)
```

Alternatively you could skip the start number and use `total || 0` and satisfy not passing the `0` initially but I wouldn't recommend it.

The reason you got `NaN` is because the second iteration you are attempting to look up a property on an object (once autboxed from a primitive) that doesn't exist, giving you `undefined + <Number>`. It's also the same reason it will work *as is* if your array only has 2 members.

> If no `initialValue` was provided, then `previousValue` will be equal to
>   the first value in the array and `currentValue` will be equal to the
>   second.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Description)

Also note these methods do not mutate the original array, so the code you currently have is throwing away the results (although you have the output there, so maybe you know that already and you're in a REPL).

Comment: It does **not** need a start value: [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @Andreas Well I mean it does in this example. I'll make that clearer.

Comment: @Andreas You're right, I just checked the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Just give a start value for reduce and change the first argument inside.

```js
var people = [{
        name: 'shihan', //persons name, favorite color, and age
        color: 'blue',
        age: 22
    }, {
        name: 'john',
        color: 'blue',
        age: 21
    }, {
        name: 'pete',
        color: 'blue',
        age: 26
    }],
    newPerson = people.filter(function(x) {
        return x.color === 'blue'
    });
document.write(newPerson.reduce((a, b) => a + b.age, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through the array

```
var sum=0;
for(var i=0;i<people.length; i++) {
    sum+= people[i].age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in just making sum available generally

```
Array.prototype.sum = function(){
     return this.reduce((sum,current) => sum + current,0);
};
```

In this instance you could get the sum of ages with a map.

```js
Array.prototype.sum = function(){
     return this.reduce((sum,current) => sum + current,0);
};
var ages = [
 { age : 1 },
 { age : 2 },
 { age : 3 },
 { age : 4 }
];
var agesum = ages.map(arr => arr.age).sum();
console.log(agesum);
```